# Best way to do TRC20 transaction callbacks

Tags: blockchain

I am working on TRC20 network and I am using it to monitor a list (1000+) addresses to check if there are any USDT being sent in.

I tried 2 methods but I am not sure what is the best approach to do this.

Method 1: which is the .watch() function from the official documentation
https://developers.tron.network/reference/methodwatch

I am able to get lots of transaction information, but I did a test with my own transactions and its really wonky, as in I am not able to catch my own transactions reliably.

Method 2: calling the api to get all transactions of a wallet address.
https://developers.tron.network/reference/get-transaction-info-by-account-address

The issue with this is I have to do polling every x minutes on 1000+ addresses ( which will grow in the future).

Would like to ask if anyone could share how do platforms monitor their addresses. I joined the tron developer community and its full of scammers.

Method 2:

Answer (score 0):

Neither or, at least the ones I have seen they use events monitoring on the contract, the simple, peasant way of doing it is calling the tronlink API:

```js
    const USDT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS = 'TR7NHqjeKQxGTCi8q8ZY4pL8otSzgjLj6t';
    let blockNuber = 0; // get lastest block if you're starting or get last check from DB
    
    let url = `https://api.trongrid.io/v1/contracts/${USDT_CONTRACT_ADDRESS}/events?block_number=${blockNumber}`;
    
      let events = [];
    
      while (true) {
        const response = await axios.get(url);
        const json = response.data;
        events = events.concat(json.data);
    
        if (!json?.meta?.links?.next) {
          break;
        }
    
        url = response.data.meta.links.next;
      }
      // do wathever you want with events!
```

And save last block number you checked, that way you can check that in continuos loop or some sort of that.
I call that in parallel with 10 threads and call that function every 5 minutes.
I know is not a complete answer but I think at least it can help you figure it out